# I am using indexof('custom'),its working for 1 condition but failed in another condition

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi in my shoping cart i have put a check for itemname and carttotal .

```
if (carttotal >'500' && itemname.indexOf("Custom") == 0)   
    {

    //code to display popup
    }
```

There are to situation 1 in which it works fine and other when it fails:

working condition: if i added itemname "custom" at last then its working:

E.g.:

First item in cart is anything "abc"  and last itemname is "custom" and carttotal is >500.then popup display fine.

NOT WORKING CASE:if i added itemname "custom" at first and after that i added some more items like "xyz".and carttotal is >500.then popup does not  display.

Comment: Isn't the index of the first item `0`? That would mean your `if` condition would fail if "Custom" is the first item.

Comment: itemname                            price

2nd item )abc                         100

1st item)custom                      600
                       carttotal  700

not works.


condition2:
itemname                          price
2nd item )custom                      600
1st item)abc                         100


                            carttotal  700


works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code checks to see if `Custom` is the *first* item in the list (an index of `0`). What you really want to do, to check if `Custom` is present *anywhere* in the list, is see if `indexOf('Custom')` returns a value that is `> -1`, as `-1` is the failing value for `indexOf()`, not 0 or another falsy value. For example:

```
var carttotal = /* Your cart total */
var products = [ /* Lots of products */ ];

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    itemname = products[i];

    if(carttotal > 500 && products.indexOf('Custom') > -1) {    // `products`, not `itemname`
        // Popup
    }
}
```

Here, I'm also checking against `products`, assuming that is your array of products. If `itemname` is, then use that.

Comment: itemname                            price

2nd item )abc                         100

1st item)custom                      600
                       carttotal  700

not works.


condition2:
itemname                          price
2nd item )custom                      600
1st item)abc                         100


                            carttotal  700


works fine.

Comment: Explain your problem better. It's difficult to work out what the correct behaviour should be from your description. My understanding is that you want the popup to appear if `custom` _isn't_ in the list **and** `carttotal > 500`

Comment: I want popup only when there is "custom" in list.What is happening now  according to my condition.IF i added any item with name "abc" first time ,and at last i added itemname "custom" and carttotal>500 ,this condition working. Now check this condition carefully:IF i added any item "custom" at first time and then added itemname "abc" at last and carttotal>500 then popup does not display.Is this clear for you now?    Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that's cleared things up. Please see my edits - hopefully the answer is correct this time

Comment: Hi Bojangles its not working please check my code.                      var  itemname=$('#Hidden9').val();
var compare_value_oldd="$500";
var compare_value_neww=parseFloat(compare_value_oldd.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g,''));
for(var i = 0; i < itemname.length; i++) {
if (parseFloat(totalnumm.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g,'')) > compare_value_neww    && itemname.indexOf("Custom") > -1 )
{
 if ($.cookie('test_status1') != '2') {                                   
      ///popup code here
$.cookie('test_status1', '2', { expires: 30 });
   }


   }



  }

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. What's actually in `itemname`? Try removing the `$.cookie()` lines to make sure they aren't causing a problem. My code assumes `itemname` is an array which it appears it is not in your code

Comment: Itemname is the name of item that displays in the cart.i just fetch itemname through hidden field  variable.and then i compare it.so thats why it picks up tha last name of item.how i can use this in loop?